# How to play simple slideshow of multiple images in WPF UserControl in Winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have WPF UserControl within ElementHost in a Windows Form. I had to use the interop because I needed easy zooming and panning functionality. And everything is perfect except I can't play slideshow.

Funny thing is that each image can be display with selection in ListBox without any problem. But when I loop through the list to play movie, it only shows the last image. I put Thread.Sleep(1000), this.Refresh(), or anything else in each loop in vain. Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating following code in the UserControl and calling its Refresh method whenever needed.

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public void Refresh()
    {
        //this.Refresh();
          this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, (MyDelegate) delegate() { });        
    }
```